# Finding a way to create a list of array from another complex array

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm facing a complex task that make me headache. Assuming that I have option array like this:

```
$options = {'Color' => {'Red, Green, Blue'},
          'Size' => {'S','M','L'},
          'Material' => {'Wool','Cotton'}
          }
```

Also, I have a set of mapping:

```
{'Red', 'S', 'Cotton'}
{'Red', 'M', 'Cotton'}
{'Blue', 'S', 'Wool'}
```

When I select an option by a certain way (from selectbox etc..), for example, when I select 'Red' I want to have an array like this:

```
$redArray =  {
               'Size' => {'S','M'},
               'Material' => {'Cotton'}
               }
```

Similarly, when I select 'M' option, the result will be:

```
$mArray = {
            'Color => {'Red'},
            'Material' => {'Cotton'}
           }
```

Maybe my explanation is not clear enough, hope you can help me...Thanks

Comment: algorithm? sounds like a trivial loop. process each element.

Comment: It's either so simple that it's complexity is exaggerated in the question, or so complicated that the question seems overly simple... Needs more clarification.

Comment: OK, let me update my question

Answer (score 2):

use `array_merge_recursive` for example

```
$ar1=array('color'=>"green");
$ar2=array('color'=>"blue");
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);

output :
   Array
    (
   [color] => Array
    (
        [0] => green
        [1] => blue
    )

   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input:
{Red, Medium, Cotton}
{Red, Large)
{Blue, Medium)
(Green, Small)
(Green, Large)

$r = array();
foreach($input as $i)
{
    $k = $i[0];
    foreach(array_slice($i, 1) as $s) {
    $r[$k][] = $s;
    $r[$k][] = array_unique($r[$k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple foreach is easy

```
// Your initial arrays
$from = array(
    array("Red", "Medium"),
    array("Red", "Large"),
    array("Blue", "Medium"),
    array("Green", "Small"),
    array("Green", "Large")
);

// The output array
$output = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($from); $i++) {
    $a = $from[$i];

    if (!array_key_exists($a[0], $output) {
        $output[$a[0]] = array();
    }
    if (!in_array($a[1], $output[$a[0]]) {
        $output[$a[0]][] = $a[1];
    }
}
```

Note that it could be easier to take simple key/value array in the `from` variable.